# Launch xterm with no border/decoration in X11/MWM

Tags: x11, freebsd, xterm

I am trying to open a xterm window but without border and window decorations using X11 and MWM as window manager.

I have  tried:

```
xterm -bw 0
```

But that does not even remove the border, nor the decoration.
I would not like to modify the .Xresources as it is just for a few xterm instances. I am using FreeBSD although I guess question is related to X11 and Xterm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mwm man page describes how you can set the client decorations with a resource line in your ~/.mwmrc such as

```
 Mwm*XTerm.clientDecoration: none
```

which matches all xterms. Instead of a class name `XTerm` you can use a name that you give to the particular xterm instances when you start them, eg `xterm -name nodeco ...` and the configuration `Mwm*nodeco.clientDecoration: none`